# Reduce type declaration in java generic base class

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way in Java to not specify the second type (ID_TYPE) and use it for my generic methods anyway?

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<ENTITY extends Identifiable<ID_TYPE>, ID_TYPE extends Serializable
```

I do not want to declare the second type, because it's already defined in my interface:

```
public interface Identifiable<TYPE extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
```

If I could get ride of the second type in the base class I could use my base class like this:

```
public class MyClass extends MyBaseClass<SomeOtherClass>
```

Comment: Since `Identifiable` takes an `<TYPE>` argument, presumably it's because some of the methods defined by the interface uses `TYPE` as a parameter type or a return type. In your `MyClass` declaration, what type would those methods be using, when you don't declare `ID_TYPE` in `MyBaseClass`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `class MyBaseClass<ENTITY extends Identifiable<ENTITY>>`. instead of having `TYPE` be independent of `ENTITY`?

Comment: The goal is fix the Type `ID_TYPE`, because it is used in a method which takes `ID_TYPE` as an argument `findById(ID_TYPE id)`.

Comment: I also tried it with `public <T extends Serializable> Optional<ENTITY> findById(T id) {` but then even the `Serializable`is redundantly declared. And it's also more complicate to override the method in a child class.